# Why I am not getting prompt while copying hidden files in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

Whenever I copy files on my OS Windows 7, I usually not get prompt about hidden files as in windows XP.

The problem I have that I need to check whether hidden files get copied or not each time by enabling "show hidden files" option.

P.S. - I copy files at that time "show hidden files" is unchecked i.e. off.

Please tell reason behind it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a suggestion (workaround), use XCOPY and a batch file (or via command prompt) as this has commands which allow you to include hidden files (excluded as default). If you're doing this often it means you have can just save the file down, but if the directories are constantly changing this may be too much work for what it is worth.

Any way,  `/H` as part of XCopy will copy hidden and system files and folders. The default is `/N`

So,

```
xcopy "folderSourcePath" "folderDestinationPath" /N
```

Although I think you can leave the N off as it's implicit. The above code should copy all non-hidden files/folders.

Comment: can I achieve it without using commands? I mean what if I do simply copy - paste using right clicks?

Comment: I have no method with right click - my searches returned no results either so I'm hoping the above may be of use but it is a work around I'm afraid.